# How can I redo my function so that it asks for the user's input everytime it loops?

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, global-variables

I'm relatively new to python and computer programming in general so please bear with me.

I've created a program in python that asks the user for the number of sides of a die and how many dice they want to roll, and then give them the number that they roll using those parameters. After they roll, I want to ask the user for their roll and sides again but my code only does everything after the `dice(sides,rolls)` function. I've tried making the "sides" and "rolls" variables `global` and then putting them inside the function, but it kept giving me an error. Here is my code:

```
import random
sides = int(input("Please input the number of sides of your die.\n"))
rolls = int(input("Please input the number of dice you wish to roll.\n"))
def dice(sides, rolls):
        y = random.randrange(sides)
        z = y * rolls
        print("Rolling " + str(rolls) + " dice with " + str(sides) + " sides...")
        print("You rolled a", z)
        roll_again = input("Would you like to roll? [y/n]\n")
        while(roll_again == 'y'):
            dice(sides, rolls)
dice(sides, rolls)
```

Thanks in advance.